# getting class of object wrapper from class of primitive types

Tags: java, reflection

So I have a object whose methods I get using reflection. I am getting expected arguments as `Object... methodArgs` and this cannot be changed. After checking the name I am doing a parameters check

```
            if (method.getName().equals(methodName))
            {
                Class<?>[] pType  = method.getParameterTypes();
                if(pType.length == methodArgs.length)
                {
                    boolean methodMatched = true;
                    for (int i = 0; i < methodArgs.length; i++) 
                    {
                        if(!pType[i].equals(methodArgs[i].getClass()))
                        {
                            methodMatched = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if(methodMatched)
                    {
                        targetMethod = method;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

but it will fail for methods let say `public void dummyMethod(boolean b);` as `methodArgs[i]..getClass()` will return `Boolean`. How can I achieve this?

Somehow I want to convert `boolean` to 'Boolean' for pType. It can be any primitive data type.

I tried

```
Class.forName(boolean.class.getName()).getConstructor().newInstance().getClass();
```

but it does not work giving

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: boolean
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. (Note: The number of primitive types is limited, so I would probably test each one and handle them in a separate way)

Comment: to prevent Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: boolean use Class.forName(Boolean.class.getName()).getConstructor().newInstance().getClass();

Comment: Yeah handling each primitive value could be one way. I was wondering if there is an alternate approach.